# Resizebox within equation environment

Tags: graphics, equations, boxes

How does the resize command work with the `equation` environment? The following code results in an error.

```
\begin{equation}\label{model3_coef}
  \resizebox{0.91\hsize}{!}{y_{t}^{3} = -145.071 - 0.003*x_{t-1}^{7} + 0.459*x_{t}^{6} +
  0.001*x_{t-1}^{8} -5.071*x_{t-1}^{9} + 7.322*x_{t-1}^{5} - 0.235*x_{t-1}^{1}  }
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! What are you actually trying to do? That is, what did you hope this code would do?

Comment: Does the code work if you remove the `\resizebox`?  Also, the parameter needs to be put in math mode: `\resizebox{<length>}{<height>}{$ math content $}`.

Comment: it works like `\mbox` (so takes you out of math mode)  but scaling text is always the wrong thing to do

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't accept any of the answers?

Answer (score 23):

The parameter for `\resizebox` is in `text` mode. Thus you need to explicitly go into math mode:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{model3_coef}
    \resizebox{0.91\hsize}{!}{%
        $y_{t}^{3} = -145.071 - 0.003 x_{t-1}^{7} + 0.459 x_{t}^{6} + 0.001 x_{t-1}^{8} 
                     -5.071 x_{t-1}^{9} + 7.322 x_{t-1}^{5} - 0.235 x_{t-1}^{1}$%      
        }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Stan: If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: This does not seem to be working for multiple equations in `equation` environment.

Comment: @IgotiT: Using `\resizebox` for each equation should work. I would suggest you post a new question and include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem and shows what you tried..

Comment: @PeterGrill: For resizebox to work for multiple equations in align environment we need put `resizebox` command before every equation.

Comment: @IgotiT: You probably need separate `\resizebox` for _before_ and _after_ the `align`. Instead of describing it here in the comments, I still suggest you post a new question with fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.  You probably won't be the last person to come across this issue so having a separate question specfic to resizing in `align` would be useful to others as well.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Posted http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360729/resizebox-command-for-equations-in-align-enviroment

Answer (score 10):

An alternative is package `resizegather`, which shrinks equations of environment `gather` of package `amsmath` to `\linewidth`, if the equation is too large:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{resizegather}

\begin{document}
\hrule % show text width
\begin{gather}\label{model3_coef}
  y_{t}^{3} = -145.071 - 0.003*x_{t-1}^{7} +
  0.459*x_{t}^{6} +
  0.001*x_{t-1}^{8} -5.071*x_{t-1}^{9} + 7.322*x_{t-1}^{5} -
  0.235*x_{t-1}^{1}
\end{gather}
\begin{multline}\label{model3_coef_alt}
  y_{t}^{3} = -145.071 - 0.003*x_{t-1}^{7}  
  + 0.459*x_{t}^{6} + 0.001*x_{t-1}^{8} 
  \\
  - 5.071*x_{t-1}^{9} + 7.322*x_{t-1}^{5} - 0.235*x_{t-1}^{1}
\end{multline}
\hrule % show text width
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

In this case of the page layout, the equation is still much too large for a pleasant outcome and package `resizegather` warns, if the scaling factor gets below a threshold (default: 95%, can be configured with option `warningthreshold`):

```
Package resizegather Warning: Equation line 1 is too large by 92.86534pt
(resizegather)                in environment `gather' on input line 12.
```

It should be kept in mind, that the reader should be able to read the equation. Since also the indexes gets scaled down, many readers would need magnifying glasses. Therefore the second equation shows the same equation split in two lines and in its natural size. Package `amsmath` provides many ways to split an equation.

Comment: This is really nice. Thanks. Though, is it possible to use this selectively? I.e., apply it only to what ever `gather` that I wish and not all?

Comment: @Pouya There are options to enable and disable the behavior: `\resizegathersetup{enable}` and `\resizegathersetup{disable}`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `\scalebox` as in this example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\begin{document}
        \begin{equation}      
            \scalebox{4.0}{$
                    y=2x+5
                $}
        \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Bad idea, this will result in very uneven fontsizes throughout your document: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text