# Resizebox command for equations in align enviroment

Tags: amsmath, resize

I am trying to reduce the size of math equations so as to fit them within the margin of a page. I took the idea of this command from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237046/resizebox-within-equation-environment/237051?noredirect=1#comment888884_237051). For this command to work for multiple equations in align environment we need to put resize box command before every equation written within $...$. Is it possible to apply this command directly on the whole set of equations?
The code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\resizebox{0.91\hsize}{!}{$u=\left(\,\frac{d_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{4}-d_{{2}}\mu\right)\left({\frac { c_{{1}}\cosh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu
}x \right) +c_{{2}}\sinh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x
 \right)  }{  c_{{1}}\sinh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x \right) +c_{{2}}\cosh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x \right) }}\right)^{2}-\,\frac{d_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2
}}{6}+\,\frac{2d_{{2}}\mu}{3}$}\\
&\resizebox{0.91\hsize}{!}{$v= \left( \,\frac{e_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{4}-e_{{2}}\mu \right)\left({\frac { c_{{1}}\cosh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu
}x \right) +c_{{2}}\sinh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x
 \right)  }{  c_{{1}}\sinh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x \right) +c_{{2}}\cosh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x \right) }}\right)^{2}-\,\frac{2e_{{2}}{
\lambda}^{2}}{3}+\,\frac{2e_{{2}}\mu}{3}$}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&u=\left(\,\frac{d_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{4}-d_{{2}}\mu\right)\left({\frac { c_{{1}}\cosh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu
}x \right) +c_{{2}}\sinh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x
 \right)  }{  c_{{1}}\sinh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x \right) +c_{{2}}\cosh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x \right) }}\right)^{2}-\,\frac{d_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2
}}{6}+\,\frac{2d_{{2}}\mu}{3}\\
&v= \left( \,\frac{e_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{4}-e_{{2}}\mu \right)\left({\frac { c_{{1}}\cosh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu
}x \right) +c_{{2}}\sinh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x
 \right)  }{  c_{{1}}\sinh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x \right) +c_{{2}}\cosh \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x \right) }}\right)^{2}-\,\frac{2e_{{2}}{
\lambda}^{2}}{3}+\,\frac{2e_{{2}}\mu}{3}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't do this!! If you box each cell separately you will have inconsistent font sizes within the same expression. It's bad enough to apply `\resizebox` to the entire expression which gives inconsistent font sizes within the document.

Comment: Also you are using `align` but not using any alignment points, why not `&=` to align the = ?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternate presentation that you could consider for this specfic case:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
u&=\biggl(\frac{d_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{4}-d_{{2}}\mu\biggr)
    C - \frac{d_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{6}+ \frac{2d_{{2}}\mu}{3}
\\
v&= \biggl( \frac{e_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{4}-e_{{2}}\mu \biggr)
    C - \frac{2e_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{3}+\frac{2e_{{2}}\mu}{3}
\\
u&=\biggl(\frac{d_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{4}-d_{{2}}\mu\biggr)
C -\frac{d_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{6}+\frac{2d_{{2}}\mu}{3}
\\
v&= \biggl( \frac{e_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{4}-e_{{2}}\mu \biggr)
C -\frac{2e_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{3}+\frac{2e_{{2}}\mu}{3}
\\
\shortintertext{where}
C &= \biggl({\frac { c_{{1}}\cosh ( \frac{1}{2}\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\mu
}x ) +c_{{2}}\sinh ( \frac{1}{2}\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\mu}x)  }
{  c_{{1}}\sinh ( \frac{1}{2}\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\mu}x ) +c_{{2}}\cosh ( \frac{1}{2}\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\mu}x ) }}\biggr)^{\!2}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

there is no need to apply scaling here, just linebreak to stay within bounds

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
u&=\biggl(\,\frac{d_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{4}-d_{{2}}\mu\biggr)
   \biggl({\frac { c_{{1}}\cosh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu
}x ) +c_{{2}}\sinh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x)  }
{  c_{{1}}\sinh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x ) +c_{{2}}\cosh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x ) }}\biggr)^{2}\\
&\qquad-\,\frac{d_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2
}}{6}+\,\frac{2d_{{2}}\mu}{3}
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}
v&= \biggl( \,\frac{e_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{4}-e_{{2}}\mu \biggr)
\biggl({\frac { c_{{1}}\cosh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu
}x ) +c_{{2}}\sinh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x
 )  }{  c_{{1}}\sinh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x ) +c_{{2}}\cosh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x ) }}\biggr)^{2}\\
&\qquad-\,\frac{2e_{{2}}{
\lambda}^{2}}{3}+\,\frac{2e_{{2}}\mu}{3}
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
u&=\biggl((\,\frac{d_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{4}-d_{{2}}\mu\biggr)
\biggl({\frac { c_{{1}}\cosh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu
}x ) +c_{{2}}\sinh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x
 )  }{  c_{{1}}\sinh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x ) +c_{{2}}\cosh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x ) }}\biggr)^{2}\\
&\qquad-\,\frac{d_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2
}}{6}+\,\frac{2d_{{2}}\mu}{3}
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}
v&= \biggl(( \,\frac{e_{{2}}{\lambda}^{2}}{4}-e_{{2}}\mu \biggr)
\biggl({\frac { c_{{1}}\cosh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu
}x ) +c_{{2}}\sinh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x
 )  }{  c_{{1}}\sinh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x ) +c_{{2}}\cosh ( \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{
\lambda}^{2}-4\,\mu}x ) }}\biggr)^{2}\\
&\qquad-\,\frac{2e_{{2}}{
\lambda}^{2}}{3}+\,\frac{2e_{{2}}\mu}{3}
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Looking in nice *David Carlisle* solution I observe, that the most space consuming part in all four equations are the same:

```
\frac{c_{1}\cosh(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\lambda^{2}-4\,\mu}x) +
                    c_{2}\sinh(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\lambda^{2}-4\,\mu}x)}
           {c_{1}\sinh(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\lambda^{2}-4\,\mu}x ) +
                    c_{2}\cosh (\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\lambda^{2}-4\,\mu}x)}
```

If this part you replace with some variable, for example `D`, than you can write your equation system for example like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Let
\begin{equation}
D = \left(\frac{c_{1}\cosh(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\lambda^{2}-4\,\mu}x) +
                        c_{2}\sinh(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\lambda^{2}-4\,\mu}x)}
               {c_{1}\sinh(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\lambda^{2}-4\,\mu}x ) +
                        c_{2}\cosh (\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\lambda^{2}-4\,\mu}x)}
    \right)\, ,
\end{equation} 
than:
    \begin{align}
u & = \left(\frac{d_{2}{\lambda}^{2}}{4}-d_{2}\mu\right)
        D^{2} - \frac{d_{2}{\lambda}^{2}}{6} + \frac{2d_{2}\mu}{3}  \\
v & = \left(\frac{e_{2}\lambda^{2}}{4}-e_{2}\mu \right)
        D^{2} - \frac{2e_{2}\lambda^{2}}{3} + \frac{2e_{2}\mu}{3}   \\
u & = \left(\frac{d_{2}{\lambda}^{2}}{4} - d_{2}\mu\right)
        D^{2} - \frac{d_{2}\lambda^{2}}{6} + \frac{2d_{2}\mu}{3}   \\
v & = \left(\frac{e_{2}\lambda^{2}}{4} - e_{2}\mu \right)
        D^{2} - \frac{2e_{2}\lambda^{2}}{3} + \frac{2e_{2}\mu}{3}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

By the way, in above code I clean-up all surplus braces and spaces and wrong parenthesis ...

**Edit:** When I upload my answer I for unknown reason didn't see almost the same answer of *Peter Grill*. In doubt what to do now, I first delete my answer but later I observe (very) small differences in code and form (probably form of *Peter* is more correct) and on the end decided to left answer ...

Comment: You can remove the outer parentheses around the fraction in the first equation.

Comment: of course, I will do this ...