# Best way to resize an equation without affencting its tag and other values?

Tags: resize

Some time, in my typesetting work, I need to resize some equations like in the example (it's just a for explanation purposes):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}

\begin{document}
\flushbottom
\section{Section}
\blindtext\footnote{Equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2 x_{1} + 2 x_{2} + 2 x_{3} + 2 x_{4} + 2 x_{5} + 2 x_{6} + 2 x_{7} + 2 x_{8} + 2 x_{9} + 2 x_{10} + 2 x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2 x_{13} }{z}\end{equation}}
\begin{equation}
\frac{2 x_{1} + 2 x_{2} + 2 x_{3} + 2 x_{4} + 2 x_{5} + 2 x_{6} + 2 x_{7} + 2 x_{8} + 2 x_{9} + 2 x_{10} + 2 x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2 x_{13} }{z}
\end{equation}
\blindtext
{\small\begin{equation}
\frac{2 x_{1} + 2 x_{2} + 2 x_{3} + 2 x_{4} + 2 x_{5} + 2 x_{6} + 2 x_{7} + 2 x_{8} + 2 x_{9} + 2 x_{10} + 2 x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2 x_{13} }{z}
\end{equation}}\relax


\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to know if there is a solution that:

1. Does non affect the resized equation's tag like in eq. (3) in the example. I need it in the default size.
2. Does not affect the footnotes equations tag. (This does not happen in the example but in some solutions I tried.)
3. Does not affect the `baselinestretch` of the last paragraph's line before the resized equation (like in the example)
4. Does prevent a pagebreak in between the resized equation and the corresponding paragraph.
5. Does work with multiline aligned ambients (align, alignat).

**Edit.** The solution I generally use is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{normal}[\normalsize]{\normalsize (}{)}
\newtagform{footnotesize}[\footnotesize]{\footnotesize (}{)}
\usetagform{normal}

\begin{document}
\flushbottom
\section{Section}
\blindtext\footnote{\usetagform{footnotesize}Equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2 x_{1} + 2 x_{2} +  2 x_{3} + 2 x_{4} +  2 x_{5} + 2 x_{6} +  2 x_{7} + 2 x_{8} +  2 x_{9} + 2 x_{10} +  2 x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2 x_{13} }{z}\end{equation}}
\begin{equation}
\frac{2 x_{1} + 2 x_{2} +  2 x_{3} + 2 x_{4} +  2 x_{5} + 2 x_{6} +  2 x_{7} + 2 x_{8} +  2 x_{9} + 2 x_{10} +  2 x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2 x_{13} }{z}
\end{equation}
\blindtext
\par\vskip -\baselineskip
{\small\begin{equation}
\frac{2 x_{1} + 2 x_{2} +  2 x_{3} + 2 x_{4} +  2 x_{5} + 2 x_{6} +  2 x_{7} + 2 x_{8} +  2 x_{9} + 2 x_{10} +  2 x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2 x_{13} }{z}
\end{equation}}\relax    

\end{document}
```

[image]

But it does not prevent page-break between the equation and the corresponding paragraph. Also I was searching for something simpler and quicker.

**Note1.** I know that I can reduce the math operators space (e.g. \!+\! in the simpler way) but I really need a generic solution to "resize" the whole content of the math-environment except for the tag.

**Note2.** Feel free to correct my english and the technical terms if they are wrong or not easy to understand.

Comment: Personal comment, unrelated to the issue: Don't put numbered equations in footnotes (IMHO, of course). I see at least two reasons: 1) if an equation is important enough to have a number, it doesn't belong in a footnote, and 2) the consecutive numbering of equations in the text is disrupted.

Comment: If you could change content: `\frac{2 (x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_13)}{z}` etc. (saves space) or even `\frac{2\sum^{13}_{i=1} x_i}{z}`.

Comment: @TeXnician I'm a typesetter. I typeset papers for scientific journals. I can't change the math form of an expression.

Comment: That's why I wrote "IF" and "COULD".

Comment: @campa I agree with you. But I'm only a  typesetter and I see every day very bad typesetting. (Scientist are not typesetters... not all at least).

Comment: Can [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237046/82917) (and answers therein) help?

Comment: @campa Thank you. I already knew about that solution. It works but I'm searching for something that works with every math-ambient (e.g. align, alignat...) I mean mutliline aligned ambients.

Comment: Only a partial solution (hence only a comment): you can hack into `amsmath` tag-making to force the tag number to be in normal size: `\makeatletter \def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\normalsize#1}} \makeatother`. In this way font size changing command like `\small` won't effect the equation tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using `amsmath`, you can redefine `\maketag@@@` to keep the "normal" size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\newmaketag{%
  \def\maketag@@@##1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\normalsize##1}}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Ordinary display:
\begin{equation}
a + b + c = d
\end{equation}

Small numbered display:
\begin{small}
\begin{equation}
a + b + c = d
\end{equation}
\end{small}

\newmaketag
Small numbered display with redefined tag:
\begin{small}
\begin{equation}
a + b + c = d
\end{equation}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

this will work with any of the `amsmath` multiline display environments, providing full-size equation numbers on every line.

if the text above the "smallified" display has more than one line, the baselines will be affected; this requires some additional care, but i haven't time to address that right now; i'll try to come back to it.

Comment: Thank you. I tested your solution and I found that you need to put the "\newmaketag command" inside the `\small` ambient else the footnotes equations tag will be affect.  I would really appreciate if you could provide a fix to the baseline's issue.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi -- i do have a workaround for the baselines, but unfortunately the system on which the information resides crashed last friday (four days ago), and it's in the hands of the systems group.  what with weekand and holiday, it won't be restored until at least tomorrow, possibly later.  (this has shut down a publisher's entire production effort, and goodness knows how much it's costing.)  thank you for the warning regarding the tag in the footnote; that hadn't been encountered here.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the incident. I can wait. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. I hope you system has been restored. If so, could you post your workaround for the baselines?

Answer (score 2):

As typeset er you have very tied hands ... Only two things besides use smaller fonts as you try in your MWE, what you can do, cross my mind:
- enclose operators `+` into curly braces, i.e.: `{+}` (as exception for this equation)
- spill-out equation to outer border

Both cases are shown in MWE below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\flushbottom
\section{Section}
\blindtext\footnote{Equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2 x_{1}{+}2 x_{2}{+}2 x_{3}{+}2 x_{4}{+}2 x_{5}{+}2 x_{6}{+}2 x_{7}{+}2 x_{8}{+}2 x_{9}{+}2 x_{10}{+}2 x_{11}{+}2 x_{12}{+}2 x_{13} }{z}
\end{equation}}
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-4em}
\begin{equation}
\frac{2 x_{1}{+}2 x_{2}{+}2 x_{3}{+}2 x_{4}{+}2 x_{5}{+}2 x_{6}{+}2 x_{7}{+}2 x_{8}{+}2 x_{9}{+}2 x_{10}{+}2 x_{11}{+}2 x_{12}{+}2 x_{13} }{z}
\end{equation}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
or with smaller font in equation
   {\small\begin{equation}
\frac{2 x_{1}{+}2 x_{2}{+}2 x_{3}{+}2 x_{4}{+}2 x_{5}{+}2 x_{6}{+}2 x_{7}{+}2 x_{8}{+}2 x_{9}{+}2 x_{10}{+}2 x_{11}{+}2 x_{12}{+}2 x_{13} }{z}
    \end{equation}}
or shortly (as pointed in comments below answer)%
    \footnote{Equation
\begin{equation}\medmuskip=0mu
\frac{2 x_{1} + 2 x_{2} + 2 x_{3} + 2 x_{4} + 2 x_{5} + 2 x_{6} + 2 x_{7} + 2 x_{8} + 2 x_{9} + 2 x_{10} + 2 x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2 x_{13} }{z}
\end{equation}
        }:
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-4em}
\begin{equation}\medmuskip=0mu
\frac{2 x_{1} + 2 x_{2} + 2 x_{3} + 2 x_{4} + 2 x_{5} + 2 x_{6} + 2 x_{7} + 2 x_{8} + 2 x_{9} + 2 x_{10} + 2 x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2 x_{13} }{z}
\end{equation}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
or with smaller font in equation
{\small\begin{equation}\medmuskip=0mu
\frac{2 x_{1} + 2 x_{2} + 2 x_{3} + 2 x_{4} + 2 x_{5} + 2 x_{6} + 2 x_{7} + 2 x_{8} + 2 x_{9} + 2 x_{10} + 2 x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2 x_{13} }{z}
    \end{equation}}

\end{document}
```

I can't say, what is more appropriate. Probably you should ask author(s), that (s)he rewrote this equation and shown him result of this test :)

**Edit:** to MWE is added part which consider @campa comment below. From picture below follows, that results are the same (it had to be ...) but use `\muskip`   make equation writing far more concise :).

[image]

Comment: I think it would be easier to issue `\medmuskip=0mu` instead of wrapping every `+` in braces... Call me lazy `;-)`

Comment: I generally use, in such cases {\thinmuskip=2mu\medmuskip=1mu\thickmuskip=3mu \begin{equation} ... \end{equation}}. But often I deal with equations with not enough math-operators to do this trick.

Comment: I agree with both above comments :) I will consider them when editing my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `{\small\begin{equation}...}` workaround is as wrong as it could be, sorry.

Here are some better solutions:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for text, recommended anyway
\usepackage{mathtools}% for \splitdfrac

\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\flushbottom

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
Some dummy text. Some dummy text. Some dummy text. Some dummy text.
Some dummy text. Some dummy text. Some dummy text. Some dummy text.
Some dummy text.\footnote{Equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2 x_{1} + 2 x_{2} + 2 x_{3} + 2 x_{4} + 2 x_{5}
      + 2 x_{6} + 2 x_{7} + 2 x_{8} + 2 x_{9} + 2 x_{10}
      + 2 x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2 x_{13} }{z}
\end{equation}}
\begin{equation}
\text{\footnotesize$\displaystyle
  \frac{2 x_{1} + 2 x_{2} + 2 x_{3} + 2 x_{4} + 2 x_{5}
        + 2 x_{6} + 2 x_{7} + 2 x_{8} + 2 x_{9} + 2 x_{10}
        + 2 x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2 x_{13} }{z}$%
}
\end{equation}
Some dummy text. Some dummy text. Some dummy text. Some dummy text.
Some dummy text. Some dummy text. Some dummy text. Some dummy text.
\begin{equation}
\frac{
  \splitdfrac{2 x_{1} + 2 x_{2} + 2 x_{3} + 2 x_{4} + 2 x_{5} + 2 x_{6} + 2 x_{7}}
             {+ 2 x_{8} + 2 x_{9} + 2 x_{10} + 2 x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2 x_{13}}
  }{z}
\end{equation}
Some dummy text. Some dummy text. Some dummy text. Some dummy text.
Some dummy text. Some dummy text. Some dummy text. Some dummy text.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  \frac{1}{z}\bigl(
    & 2 x_{1} + 2 x_{2} + 2 x_{3} + 2 x_{4} + 2 x_{5} + 2 x_{6} + 2 x_{7}\\
    & + 2 x_{8} + 2 x_{9} + 2 x_{10} + 2 x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2 x_{13}
  \bigr)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You might want to do the first as

```
\begin{equation}
\text{\footnotesize\medmuskip=0mu}$\displaystyle
  \frac{2 x_{1} + 2 x_{2} + 2 x_{3} + 2 x_{4} + 2 x_{5}
        + 2 x_{6} + 2 x_{7} + 2 x_{8} + 2 x_{9} + 2 x_{10}
        + 2 x_{11} + 2 x_{12} + 2 x_{13} }{z}$%
}
\end{equation}
```

and you'd get

[image]

An alternative is using `nccmath` and

```
\medmath{\frac{...}{...}}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed I was searching for a better solution...  but can you please explain me why the `\small`-solution is wrong? Your solutions are good but, form many reasons, I'm not allowed to use them.