# Are stmaryrd and stix packages compatibile?

Tags: math-mode, packages, math-operators, incompatibility, amssymb

I would like to know if [stmaryrd](https://ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd?lang=en) and [stix](https://ctan.org/pkg/stix) package are mutually compatibile and even if they are compatible with the packages I use into the following code: indeed, I see that \Lbag and \Rbag delimiters are different (is right?) into stmaryrd and stix package and moreover I see there appear other symbols which are present into amssymb package but strangerly I did not find any incompatibile into the linked guides.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,textwidth=17cm,textheight=25 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontsize}
\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setcounter{footnote}{-1}
\setcounter{equation}{-1}

\newtheorem{lemma}[equation]{Lemma}

\newtheorem{proposition}[equation]{Proposizione}

\newtheorem{corollary}[equation]{Corollario}

\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Teorema}

\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%I get the following code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/614685/296807) to manipulate the fontsize of an equation.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{sequation}{O{\small}b}
 {
  \yufip_sequation:nnn {equation}{#1}{#2}
 }{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{sequation*}{O{\small}b}
 {
  \yufip_sequation:nnn {equation*}{#1}{#2}
 }{}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \yufip_sequation:nnn
 {
  \begin{#1}
  \mbox{#2$\displaystyle#3$}
  \end{#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
% Here I wrote my document using some mathematical symbols as \cup, \cap, \bigcup, \bigcap, \setminus, \bot, \top, \rightthreetimes, \leftthreetimes, \odot, \oplus etc... and any any mathematical fonts as \mathcal, \mathfrak and \mathscr
\end{document}
```

So could someone help me, please?

Comment: what do you mean by compatible here? are you asking if they look well together (the usual meaning of "compatible" or if the packages give errors if both loaded or .... ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Some time ago I added [MnSymbol](https://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol?lang=en) package but it was not compatible with amssymb: e.g. it changed \setminus symbol and even calligraphic letters; moreover the compilator reported any errors which I did not understand where find exactly.

Comment: your example does not use stix or stix2 packages either uses a _lot_ of font families (out of  maximum 16) it doesn't make sense to load amsfonts stix mathrfs yfonts and stmaryrd al at the same time . don't make us guess a failing example, show an example of your problem

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay: I have to use stmaryrd to use \Lbag and \Rbag whereas I have to use stix to use \cupplus and \capdot but I see that \lbag and \rbag commands are in both as it was for \setminus with MnSymbols and amssymb so that I would like to understand if I can use now stmaryrd and stix contemporary.

Comment: mnsymbols and stix (use stix2) are complete alternatves to amssymb using different encodings so do not mix those three but stmaryrd like mathrfs is just adding an extra font so wont clash unless you run out of fonts. but do you _really_ need stmaryrd `\Lbag` in addition to stix2 `\lbag` (⟅) ???

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well If I use \Lbag and \Rbag by stmaryrd it would be better: so I can use  stmaryrd and amssymb contemporary? However,  I understood I cannot add stix but I did not understand if the same if for sitx2: could you explain better, please?

Comment: as I said, you can use stix if you wish, just not at same time as amsymb and mnsymbol, but really your question isn't clear enough to answer. You post an error free document and ask if you make some unspecified changes if you will get errors.  Just define what you want, and if you get errors, ask a new question asking about the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use *either* `stmaryrd` *or* `stix2`. And don't load `amssymb` if you choose `stix2`: this package aims to have as wide coverage of math symbols as possible.

Now, I may understand that you prefer `\Lbag` and `\Rbag` from `stmaryrd` instead of the symbols provided by `stix2`.

It's really simple (I only load the required packages):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage[only,Lbag,Rbag]{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

$\Lbag x\Rbag$ from stmaryrd

$\lbag x\rbag$ from stix2

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, since `stix2` changes the standard `\DeclareMathSizes`, you may want to make `stmryrd` fully scalable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage[only,Lbag,Rbag]{stmaryrd}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{stmry}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{stmry}{m}{n}
 {
  <-5.5> stmary5
  <5.5-6.5> stmary6
  <6.5-7.5> stmary7
  <7.5-8.5> stmary8
  <8.5-9.5> stmary9
  <9.5->  stmary10
 }{}


\begin{document}

$\Lbag x\Rbag$ from stmaryrd

$\lbag x\rbag$ from stix2

\end{document}
```

This avoids annoying warnings and uses the correct sizes in sub/superscripts.

In case you're short of math groups, you can obtain the same effect in a slightly more complicated way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix2}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{stmry}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{stmry}{m}{n}
 {
  <-5.5> stmary5
  <5.5-6.5> stmary6
  <6.5-7.5> stmary7
  <7.5-8.5> stmary8
  <8.5-9.5> stmary9
  <9.5->  stmary10
 }{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Lbag}{\mathopen{\text{\usefont{U}{stmry}{m}{n}\symbol{"48}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Rbag}{\mathclose{\text{\usefont{U}{stmry}{m}{n}\symbol{"49}}}}

\begin{document}

$\Lbag x\Rbag$ from stmaryrd

$\lbag x\rbag$ from stix2

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer: only one question is the option "only " into \usepackage[only,Lbag,Rbag]{stmaryrd} avaible for stix or MnSymbol?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro No, sorry.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply: answer approved and upvoted. Thanks really. :-)