# How tag a quote with equations?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, quoting, tags

I would like to tag a citation with equations; more precisely I would like tag citations using the following code and I would like tag them as I tag proposition, theorem etc... I tried to use the command \begin{quote}\end{quote} and I tried also to implement into my code what done in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243662/296807) but unfortunately it does not work: so could someone help me, please?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,textwidth=17cm,textheight=25 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontsize}
\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{stix2}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setcounter{footnote}{-1}
\setcounter{equation}{-1}

\newtheorem{lemma}[equation]{Lemma}

\newtheorem{proposition}[equation]{Proposizione}

\newtheorem{corollary}[equation]{Corollario}

\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Teorema}

\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black} %Personalizzazione aspetto collegamenti ipertestuali

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%I get the following code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/614685/296807) to manipulate the fontsize of an equation.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{sequation}{O{\small}b}
 {
  \yufip_sequation:nnn {equation}{#1}{#2}
 }{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{sequation*}{O{\small}b}
 {
  \yufip_sequation:nnn {equation*}{#1}{#2}
 }{}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \yufip_sequation:nnn
 {
  \begin{#1}
  \mbox{#2$\displaystyle#3$}
  \end{#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
% Here I wrote my document using some mathematical symbols as \cup, \cap, \bigcup, \bigcap, \setminus, \bot, \top, \rightthreetimes, \leftthreetimes, \odot, \oplus etc... and any any mathematical fonts as \mathcal, \mathfrak and \mathscr


\end{document}
```

To follow an example of what I would be make: I did it using word!

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "tag a citation with equations"? I don't understand at all what the expected output is supposed to be, nor what the expected input should look like.

Comment: I want mean this: If this equation $\begin{equation}\end{equation}$ is tagged with number $n$ then putting the following quote into the code $\begin{quote}\end{quote}$ I would like it is tagged with numerb $n+1$: is now clear what I ask?

Comment: It appears you want numbering of quotes. So that is clear-ish. But how would you like it to be formatted? Where should the number appear? If you just want it to look similar to Theorems, would something like `\newtheorem{numquote}[equation]{}` work for you? If not, why not?

Comment: "is now clear what I ask?" I can not guess what you mean by tag here, it would help if you fixed your example so it has a non-empty document, and state what output you want from the example you provide

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I add on image hoping now it is clear what I ask: forgive if initially the question was not clear.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro -- I think what you are trying to say is that quotes should be visibly numbered in the same style as display equations.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro  `\begin{equation} \text{this is a quote}\end{equation}` does what you ask

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: not if the quote is longer than a line.

Comment: @WillieWong parbox, minipage, ...

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro note the image helped but you didn't fix your example which had no example text and mostly consisted of code unrelated to the question `\usepackage{soulutf8}`,`\usepackage{yfonts}`, ... (do not load amsfonts and stix2 you can not use both sets at the same time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear in what your “quote” should behave. I assume it should do the same as the standard `quotation` environment.

I also provide for `\tag` (not `\tag*`, which could be done if needed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newenvironment{tagquotation}{%
  \begin{equation}
  \global\tagquotationtagfalse
  \hspace{\leftmargin}%
  \hspace{-0.5em}%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\leftmargin\relax}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}% like quotation
  \let\tag\tagquotationtag
}{%
  \end{minipage}\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
  \iftagquotationtag\tag{\thetagquotationtag}\fi
\end{equation}}
\newif\iftagquotationtag
\newcommand{\tagquotationtag}[1]{%
  \gdef\thetagquotationtag{#1}%
  \global\tagquotationtagtrue
}

\begin{document}

\ref{test}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{quotation}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\end{quotation}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\begin{tagquotation}\tag{x}\label{test}
\lipsum[4][1-4]
\end{tagquotation}
\lipsum[5][1-4]
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[6][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Removing the `\tag` command, the output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am still not clear on all the requirements; but the following should get you started.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{numquote}{\vskip\abovedisplayskip\refstepcounter{equation}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth - 5em\relax}}{\end{minipage}\hfill(\theequation)\vskip\belowdisplayskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}

Here be some text

\begin{numquote}\label{quote1}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{numquote}

The quoted passage \eqref{quote1} is from lipsum.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Explanations:

The code creates a new numbered quote environment called `numquote` using the

```
\newenvironment{<NAME>}{pre-code}{post-code}
```

construction. Our goal is to wrap your quoted material in a minipage (so that the width of the quoted material is less than that of the full textwidth, so that we have some space left in order to insert the equation number). So in the pre-code we will put `\begin{minipage}{<width>}` and `\end{minipage}`

The width of the minipage is decided to be `\textwidth - 5em`; you can adjust it yourself.

To support the equation number, we `\refstepcounter{equation}` before the start of the minipage environment. This increments the equation counter and allows cross referencing to work.

To print the equation number, we just print it flush with the right margin as `(\theequation)`. The vertical alignment is automatic as minipages are centered (vertically) on the line.

Beyond those basic components, there is also some amount of vertical spacing inserted before and after the quotes (to set it off from the unquoted text). Absent any other requests concerning spacing and margins, I just use the same vertical spacing as for displayed equations. You can replace the `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` by whatever you feel as an appropriate glue.

---

If you want the equation number to be top-aligned, you can edit the code slightly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{numquote}{\vskip\abovedisplayskip\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth - 5em\relax}\refstepcounter{equation}\leavevmode}{\end{minipage}\hfill (\theequation)\vskip\belowdisplayskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}

Here be some text

\begin{numquote}\label{quote1}%
    \lipsum[2]
\end{numquote}

The quoted passage \eqref{quote1} is from lipsum. 
\end{document}
```

Explanation/Caveats:

1. Adding the `[t]` optional argument to `minipage` makes it align near the top.
2. However, `\label` if used in vertical mode will create additional vertical spacing. A hack to combat this enforces leaving vertical mode. But then `\label` may generate an extra space character, so we put `%` after `\label`. (Or you can put the `\label` at the end of the quote.)

Comment: @WilliWong Hi, it seems your code is the best for typesetting but unfortunately I see that the tag is put below and not alongside: could I ask if it is possibile to put the tag alongside?

Comment: If you mean align the tag to the top of the quote, see edit.

Comment: You can do the same with egreg's answer: because he wrapped things in `equation`, which places the tag more smartly, you can just add `[t]` to `{minipage}` in his solution and you will get top-aligned tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify all constructs use the same counter:

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\newtheorem{prop}[equation]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}

\renewenvironment{quote}
{\begin{equation}\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}\raggedright}
{\end{minipage}\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  eq=1
\end{equation}

\begin{quote}
  a quote
\end{quote}

\begin{prop}
  a prop
\end{prop}

\begin{thm}
  a theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{quote}
  another quote
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems your code works perfectly besides it seems it is not possibile enable (if it is necessary) the enumeration using the "star" (*) option: so I hazard to use "newenviroment" rather than "renewenviroment" and  "myquote" rather than quote so that I a want tag a citation I use myquote environment whereas if I want not do it then I use simply (standard) quote environment.  Do you think I did a good thing?

Comment: Could I ask moreover if it is possible to center the minipage as the default quote command do automatically? Indeed, it seem to me that the code you wrote move excessively the text on the right. Forgive the bother.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro _you_ posted an image of a required layout with equations and quotes flush left. So that's what I did. remove `fleqn` to get centering