# Arranging equation after leftrightarrow sign

Tags: amsmath

How to arrange the equation after `Leftrightarrow` sign?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        & \Leftrightarrow - \scalebox{0.975}{$\biggl(\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\left( a_1 + \left( \alpha + \mu\right)\right)^2 + a_1 a_2\right) + \left( a_1 + \left(\alpha + \mu\right)\right)\gamma \rho \biggr)$} > 0 \\
        & \Leftrightarrow \left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\left( a_1 + \left( \alpha + \mu\right)\right)^2 + a_1 a_2\right) + \left( a_1 + \left(\alpha + \mu\right)\right)\gamma \rho < 0 \\
        & \Leftrightarrow \scalebox{0.875}{$\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)^2 + \Lambda \beta - \frac{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)^2\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}{\alpha+\mu+\rho}\right) + \left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)\gamma \rho$} < 0 \\
        & \Leftrightarrow \scalebox{0.85}{$\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)^2+ \Lambda \beta\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right) - \left(\alpha+ \mu\right)^2\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right) $} \\
        & \scalebox{0.9}{$ + \left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)\gamma \rho $} < 0 \\
        & \Leftrightarrow \scalebox{0.9}{$\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)^2\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)$} > \\
        & \scalebox{0.9}{$\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)^2+ \Lambda \beta\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right) + \left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)\gamma \rho$} \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd suggest, in the lines that begin with `\Leftrightarrow`, move the `&` *after* the `\Leftrightarrow`.  Leave it where it is in the other lines.  But there are other (better) ways to get smaller type than using `\scalebox`; I believe there's another question dealing with that, but it may take a while to find it.

Comment: Here is a question that addresses the matter of "smallifying" a display: [Use of `\small` to resize a math display affects the baseline stretch of the preceding paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/382898)

Comment: What's with the excessive use of `\left` and `\right` for every single parenthesis? I can count more than 50 [!] instances each of `\left` and `\right`...

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `IEEEeqnarray` environment from the `IEEEtrantools` package for nice alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
Using \verb|\IEEEeqnarray| with \verb|\scalebox|
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
        & \Leftrightarrow & - \scalebox{0.975}{$\biggl(\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\left( a_1 + \left( \alpha + \mu\right)\right)^2 + a_1 a_2\right) + \left( a_1 + \left(\alpha + \mu\right)\right)\gamma \rho \biggr)$} > 0 \\
        & \Leftrightarrow & \left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\left( a_1 + \left( \alpha + \mu\right)\right)^2 + a_1 a_2\right) + \left( a_1 + \left(\alpha + \mu\right)\right)\gamma \rho < 0 \\
        & \Leftrightarrow & \scalebox{0.875}{$\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)^2 + \Lambda \beta - \frac{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)^2\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}{\alpha+\mu+\rho}\right) + \left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)\gamma \rho$} < 0 \\
        & \Leftrightarrow & \scalebox{0.85}{$\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)^2+ \Lambda \beta\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right) - \left(\alpha+ \mu\right)^2\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right) $} \\
        & & \scalebox{0.9}{$ + \left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)\gamma \rho $} < 0 \\
        & \Leftrightarrow & \scalebox{0.9}{$\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)^2\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)$} > \\
        & & \scalebox{0.9}{$\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)^2+ \Lambda \beta\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right) + \left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)\gamma \rho$} \\
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

Using \verb|\IEEEeqnarray| with \verb|\footnotesize|
{\footnotesize
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
        & \Leftrightarrow & - \biggl(\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\left( a_1 + \left( \alpha + \mu\right)\right)^2 + a_1 a_2\right) + \left( a_1 + \left(\alpha + \mu\right)\right)\gamma \rho \biggr) > 0 \\
        & \Leftrightarrow & \left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\left( a_1 + \left( \alpha + \mu\right)\right)^2 + a_1 a_2\right) + \left( a_1 + \left(\alpha + \mu\right)\right)\gamma \rho < 0 \\
        & \Leftrightarrow & \left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)^2 + \Lambda \beta - \frac{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)^2\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}{\alpha+\mu+\rho}\right) \\
        & & \negmedspace {} + \left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)\gamma \rho < 0 \\
        & \Leftrightarrow & \left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)^2+ \Lambda \beta\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right) - \left(\alpha+ \mu\right)^2\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)  \\
        & & \negmedspace {} + \left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)\gamma \rho  < 0 \\
        & \Leftrightarrow & \left(\alpha+ \mu\right)^2\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right) > \left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right)\left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)^2\\
        & & \negmedspace {} + \Lambda \beta\left(\alpha + \mu + \rho\right) + \left(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\right)\gamma \rho \\
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: You may read [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/219947). Also, it is discouraged to [scale elements that contains text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425453/219947).

Comment: Okay, it works on me. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for two notes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to strongly recommend that you not use `\adustbox` *anywhere* in this math expression. Just insert a couple more line breaks by hand, if and when needed.

I would also use an `align*` environment instead of a nested `equation*/aligned` setup.

A separate observation: It may be a cathartic experience for you *not* to use `\left` and `\right` on every single parenthesis. I can count over 50 [!] instances each of these two autosizing directives. With some fairly easy analysis, the number can be brought down to 9 [yes, just nine] pairs of "big" parentheses. And, instead of using round parentheses exclusively, do also consider using square brackets (or curly braces...) from time to time to provide some simple yet very effective visual clues.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  &\Leftrightarrow -\bigl[
    (\alpha + \mu + \rho)\bigl(( a_1 + ( \alpha + \mu))^2 + a_1 a_2\bigr) 
    + \bigl( a_1 + (\alpha + \mu)\bigr)\gamma \rho \bigr] > 0 \\
  &\Leftrightarrow 
   (\alpha + \mu + \rho)\bigl(( a_1 + ( \alpha + \mu))^2 + a_1 a_2\bigr) 
    + \bigl( a_1 + (\alpha + \mu)\bigr)\gamma \rho < 0 \\
  &\Leftrightarrow 
   (\alpha + \mu + \rho)\biggl[\biggl(\frac{\Lambda\beta (\alpha+\mu+\rho)}{(\alpha+ \mu)(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)}\biggr)^{\!\!2} + \Lambda \beta 
  - \frac{(\alpha+ \mu)^2(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)}{\alpha+\mu+\rho}\biggr] \\
  &\qquad + \frac{\Lambda\beta (\alpha+\mu+\rho)}{(\alpha+ \mu)(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)}\,\gamma \rho < 0 \\
  &\Leftrightarrow (\alpha + \mu + \rho)
   \biggl(\frac{\Lambda\beta (\alpha+\mu+\rho)}{(\alpha+ \mu)(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)}\biggr)^{\!\!2}
   + \Lambda \beta(\alpha + \mu + \rho) \\
  &\qquad - (\alpha+ \mu)^2(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)  
   + \frac{\Lambda\beta (\alpha+\mu+\rho)}{(\alpha+ \mu)(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)}\,\gamma \rho  < 0 \\
  &\Leftrightarrow (\alpha+ \mu)^2(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho) >{} \\
  &\qquad (\alpha + \mu + \rho)\biggl(\frac{\Lambda\beta (\alpha+\mu+\rho)}{(\alpha+ \mu)(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)}\biggr)^{\!\!2} 
  + \Lambda \beta(\alpha + \mu + \rho) \\
  &\qquad\quad
  + \frac{\Lambda\beta (\alpha+\mu+\rho)}{(\alpha+ \mu)(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)}\,\gamma \rho 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With use of the `multlined` defined in the `mathtools` package, without scaling parts of equation systems and manuals settings of parenthesis sizes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{aligned}
\Leftrightarrow 
    & - \biggl((\alpha + \mu + \rho) \bigl((a_1 + \alpha + \mu)^2 + a_1 a_2\bigr) + ( a_1 + \alpha + \mu)\gamma \rho \biggr) > 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow {}
    & (\alpha + \mu + \rho)\bigl(( a_1 + \alpha + \mu)^2 + a_1 a_2\bigr) + (a_1 + \alpha + \mu)\gamma \rho < 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow {}
    & \begin{multlined}[t]
        (\alpha + \mu + \rho)
        \Biggl(\biggl(\frac{\Lambda\beta (\alpha+\mu+\rho)}{(\alpha+ \mu)(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)}
               \biggr)^2    \\
        + \Lambda \beta - \frac{(\alpha+ \mu)^2 (\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)}{\alpha+\mu+\rho}\Biggr)
         + \biggl(\frac{\Lambda\beta \left(\alpha+\mu+\rho\right)}{\left(\alpha+ \mu\right)\left(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho\right)}\biggr)\gamma \rho  < 0
     \end{multlined}\\
\Leftrightarrow {}
    & \begin{multlined}[t]
        (\alpha + \mu + \rho)
        \biggl(\frac{\Lambda\beta (\alpha+\mu+\rho)}{(\alpha+ \mu)(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)}\biggr)^2
        + \Lambda \beta (\alpha + \mu + \rho )     \\
        -  (\alpha+ \mu)^2 (\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)
        + \biggl(\frac{\Lambda\beta (\alpha+\mu+\rho )}{(\alpha+ \mu) (\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)}\biggr)\gamma \rho < 0  
     \end{multlined}    \\
\Leftrightarrow {}
    & \begin{multlined}[t]
        (\alpha+ \mu)^2 (\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho) >    \\
        (\alpha + \mu + \rho)
        \biggl(\frac{\Lambda\beta (\alpha+\mu+\rho)}{(\alpha+ \mu)
        (\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)}\biggr)^2            \\
        +  \Lambda \beta(\alpha + \mu + \rho) + 
        \biggl(\frac{\Lambda\beta (\alpha+\mu+\rho)}{(\alpha+ \mu)(\alpha + \mu + \gamma + \rho)}\biggr)\gamma \rho
     \end{multlined}
    \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(redlines indicate text border)