# Why does the vertical (line) spacing scrunch up for certain paragraphs?

Tags: line-spacing, verbatim

I'm writing a series of notes, and I've begun to see the vertical (line) spacing of certain paragraphs to substantially decrease compared to others. I've attached a photo to describe what I mean. The text immediately following `Exercise 6.12` and the stars is much more scrunched up than the text in the paragraph following the `verbatim` environment. Does anyone know why, and how I can prevent it? Note that the `exercise` command just receives a number, the chapter identifier, and the text-to-use.

[image]

```
\newcommand{\exercise}[3]
{\noindent\textbf{Exercise {~\ref{#2}}.\theexcounter.} (\repeatstar{#1}) \\
{#3} \stepcounter{excounter}}
...
\exercise{3}{chapter-advanced-oop}{This exercise involves the interpreter we wrote in the chapter.}
Data structures are a core and fundamental feature of programming languages. A language without them, or at least one to build others on top of, suffers severely in terms of usability. We will implement a \textit{cons}-like data structure for our interpreter. In functional programming, we often use three operations to act on data structures akin to linked lists: \textit{cons}, \textit{first}, and \textit{rest}, to construct a new list, retrieve the first element, and retrieve the rest of the list respectively. We can inductively define a cons list as follows:
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{verbatim}
A ConsList is one of:
 - new ConsList()
 - new ConsList(x, ConsList)
\end{verbatim}
\end{footnotesize}
Implement the cons data structure into your interpreter. This should involve designing the \ttt{ConsNode} class that conforms to the aforementioned data definition. Moreover, you will need to update \ttt{PrimNode} to account for the \ttt{first} and \ttt{rest} primitive operations, as well as an \ttt{empty?} predicate, which returns whether or not the cons list is empty. Finally, update the \ttt{Lvalue} class to print a stringified representation of a \ttt{ConsNode}, which amounts to printing each element, separated by spaces, inside of brackets, e.g., \ttt{[$l_0, l_1, ..., l_{n-1}]$}.
```

Comment: `\footnotesize` isn't intended to be an enviornment, you can use it that way but always make sure there is a blank line before the `\end` and before the `\begin`

Comment: Please provide code people can test rather than fragments. To elaborate: `\footnotesize` alters not only the size of the font, but the spacing of lines. Line-spacing is applied to paragraphs. So you have effectively reduced the line spacing for the entire paragraph. The `verbatim` environment inserts a paragraph break, so the line spacing reverts to normal.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Good idea, wrong example.  Better example: [Use of `\small` to resize a math display affects the baseline stretch of the preceding paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/382898)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- You're responsible for closure.  I don't think that's wrong, but the dupe you cited isn't helpful.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't have gold hammer here I just gave one vote, presumably the OP thought it was close enough

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- But it wasn't closed by the author.  Look at blue box: Community was the decisive vote.  Don;t tell me they're applying AI already !?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Community means the author voted, so community bot stepped in and closed (and the referenced dup explains this example which unfortuately your answer doesn't, adding `\par` after `verbatim` will do nothing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(La)TeX "freezes" several characteristics of a paragraph when the paragraph ends.  One of these is the baseline separation.

You have not ended the previous paragraph when starting a new block of text in `footnotesize`, and the paragraph ends in that smaller size.  Thus the baseline distance for the entire paragraph is suitable for that type size.

And as noted by @DavidCarlisle, `footnotesize` is not an environment; however, it will behave as if it is, and since environments usually end with a built-in paragraph break, the smaller baseline ends there.

You can rescue this example by revising it to use `\par{\footnotesize \begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}}`.

Comment: That's interesting that it's not designed to be an environment. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: You missed out the main case here, you need a `\par` _before_ the `{` (or before the `\begin{footnotesize}` it's that causing the text above to scrunch, a `\par` at the end won't help. as verbatim already does `\par`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Okay, I didn't test (and should have).  Fixed (and repentant).

Comment: better:-).......

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's *really* bizarre, because this seemed to have fixed it, but perhaps that was only in one lone occurrence of the problem... I had 83 separate \begin{footnotesize}\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}\end{footnotesize} environments, so it's possible that I just didn't notice the fix across them all.